# Can attributes from a different user view be used multiple times?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, normalization

Basically, my group and I have to create a normalization for userviews down to 3NF, now all the userviews are for the Seneca College Daycare, in total there are 5 userviews, and each has to do with a number of things, but mainly userviews 1-4 are about the child, parent, and workers, userview 5 is the payment form.

ex: Userview 1

```
        CHILDREN
NAME    OHIP#      DATE OF BIRTH       ALLERGY(S)   TYLENOL PERMITTED
Kevin   5334447772  Nov 2, 1999    Penicillin, Egg      Yes
Mary    4333445355  Sept 4, 1997    Egg                 Yes
```

our 3NF came down to (what my partner did)

> Form [ F_ID, Campus, Sign, DateP]
>
> Register [ R_ID, L_Name, F_Name, Relation, Apt, PosC, Hphone, Wphone,
>   E_Call, OHIP]
>
> Addr [PosC, Address, City]
>
> FormReg [F_ID, R_ID, Date]
>
> RegOAA [R_ID, OAA_ID, Relation]
>
> OAA [OAA_ID, F_Name, L_Name, HPhone, WPhone]
>
> Children [OHIP, L_Name, F_Name, Birth, Allergys, Tylenol]

userview 2

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8H14w.jpg   (too much detail to paste it here so i uploaded prnt scrn)

now the 3nf i came down to is

```
3NF
ChildDetail [Campus, Child#, ChildName, ChildBday, Allergy]
Manager [Manager#, Manager]
Supervisor [Supervisor#, Supervisor]
Worker [ChildWrkrs#, ChildWrkrs]
Family [Fam#, FamPhone#]
```

however, my partner says that we should still be using the OHIP primary key that he came up with from Userview 1

and he came up with this

> StaffAssign [Campus, Manager_ID, L_Name, F_Name]
>
> Room [RoomNum, RDescrip]
>
> Room_Staff [Campus ,RoomNum, Staff_ID, OHIP]
>
> Staff [Staff_ID, L_Name, F_Name, Occupation]
>
> Children [OHIP, L_Name, F_Name, Allergie, Birth, F_ID, E_Call]

Now, from my understanding, if my understanding is correct, we cannot use an attribute that does not exist in the userview, right? so taking OHIP from userview 1 and adding it to userview 2 shouldn't work, right?

We've been going back and forth about it, and unfortunately we are unable to reach our professor, so I was hoping someone may be able to help here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out that it is possible, as long as certain conditions are met.

If you have attributes from different userviews, they can be MERGED as long as the primary keys are the same. This becomes a cumulative design.

an example of such conditions are as follows:

```
1ST USER VIEW – OLD CUMULATIVE DESIGN

Part[Part#, description, unit_price, qty_on_hand]
Order_part[Order#, part#, sold_quantity, sold_price]
FK  order#  order
FK  part#  part

ORDER[order#, ordDate, cust#]
FK  cust#  customer
CUSTOMER[Cust#,  cName]

NEW CUMULATIVE DESIGN

PART[Part#, description, class, price, qty_on_hand]
CLASS[Class, class_desc]
ORDER_PART[ Part#, order#, quantity,  quotedPrice]
ORDER[ ord#,  ordDate, cust#]  
CUSTOMER[cust#, cName, street, city, zip, prov, country, balance, creditLimit, rep#]
REP [Rep#, rName, com_perct]
```

as you can see in the example, the PART field, has the same data, however, in the new design you'll see "class" as an added criteria. This is okay, because in an additional userview, the Parts table had an additional attribute defined as 'class', the primary key has not changed, so all that was done, was we merged the old design with the new information found, and created a new cumulative design.

So as long as the conditions are met, "transferring/using" or rather merging, attributes from a previous userview into another userview (as long as they are related, and the primary keys are the same) can be done.

**EDIT**
Also, just to make a note, you are also allowed to create your own attributes even if they do not exist in the Userview.

Example of that would be, you're filling out a form, there are plenty of criteria to use however that form can be submitted to many locations, and each location can be used as long as you have registered there, you can create an attribute that will allow you to track each form, "registration_id" as an example.